# Controlling semgnet lengths indepently in a genoPlotR plot_gene_map

Tags: r, plot, margin

I'm producing a `plot_gene_map` figure by the **genoPlotR** R package, which gives a horizontal phylogenetic tree where aligned with each leaf is a genomic segment.

I can then get the following plot as an example :

[image]

As you can see, there are two species **SP3** and **SP4** with very long segments compared to the other segments, such as the segment of the **SP1** is displayed as a tiny scale, and we cannot see all the element within that segment.

I wondered if someone is aware of a parameter in order to artificially increase the length for specific segments within the plot ?

Here is the code I used to produce the figure:

```
plot_gene_map(dna_segs=synteny2, tree=tree,
              xlims = breaks_list,comparisons = comparison,
              dna_seg_line=grey(0.7), offsets=c(30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30),
              global_color_scheme=c("e_value", "auto", "grey", "0.7"),
              limit_to_longest_dna_seg=F,dna_seg_scale = F, scale=F,  gene_type = "side_exons",minimum_gap_size = 0.05,
              annotation_cex=0.1)
```

Thank you very much for your help

## The dput files can be found here : https://github.com/Niwradel/GenoplotR_help/blob/main/Dput_files

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Hello @Quinten, I just added a link with the file in dput format, thanks for your help :-) (I removed the annotations files)